# renaming column for a partitioned table

Tags: db2, database-partitioning, db2-luw

I have a partitioned database environment with partitioned tables. Can I alter the column name for the table. I am aware that I cannot do that in following condition:

- it is being used in any views
- it is referenced in any in index definition
- it is any check constraints
- the table has a trigger

to name a few.

Besides these is there anything else that I should keep in mind?

If, yes what are those and what is the procedure for it?

Thanks

Comment: The db2 version I am using is 9.7 with fix pack 10.

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: With manual in case you mean the normal IBM documents, its not what I am looking forward. I needed some experienced people to give me insight into this. In case you can help me there, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You must thing to:

```
 -View materialized
 -Storage procedure
 -if your fields is used in Programs or scripts
 -if your field is a key in referential constraint (FK)
 -if your field is primary key (auto  increment same may be)
 -if your table with this field has autotimestamp you change will change all timestamps
 -if your field is used in view or view into view etc
```

Comment: this is to rename a column name that we generally follow. I need clarification on doing so for a partitioned column. Need I follow a different procedure for it or is there any restriction on doing so?

Comment: thanks, so if any of the above criteria is met, that means I cannot rename the column any ways, right? 

And if the condition is okay, I can rename it like normally we do the renaming, right?

Comment: yes, or you can enable all and modify all (enough difficult because you must do alter table, alter procedure, alter view, modify your program or scripts, for autotimestamp you must do a copie of table or use may be the clause overiding system value, drop contraint et recreate, alter trigger etc...) . Of course for this change you must control user doesn't working on this table too. (wrkobjlck on db2 on system i)

Comment: why -1 i dont anderstand?